# Find third point of a right triangle where the third point is on a line going through first point

Tags: trigonometry

I need to figure out an equation that will be used in a graphical drawing tool, where each angle in the polygon will be 90deg. That is to say each new point added in the polygon will be forced so that it creates a 90deg angle. So this only applies when you have 2 points or more in the polygon being drawn.

I believe I could apply this logic for each new point in the polygon:

Given two points A and B, how can I find point C forming a right triangle (with 90deg angle at B), where point C is on the line formed by point A and another known point P (the mouse cursor point) which lies on line PA.

I went as far as calculate the slope of mAB and inverted slope mBC, but unsure how to proceed from here. Do I need to find the intersection point of the lines BC and PA?

What would be the equation to find point C?

[image]

First implementation of solution is wrong (wip)
[image]

Second implementation using Doug's value for t is correct. Accepted answer.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the picture, $AC$ is just a scalar multiple of segment $AP$, which is known.  That is
$$(C-A) = t(P-A),$$
where the subtraction is done component-wise.  We also know that $AB$ and $BC$ are orthogonal, so that
$$(B-A) \cdot (C-B) = 0.$$
You can treat this is a system of equations, where we want to  solve for $C = (c_x,c_y)$.

Expanding the above equations gives
$$t(p_x-a_x)+a_x = c_x,\quad t(p_y-a_y)+a_y = c_y,$$
$$(b_x-a_x)(c_x-b_x)+(b_y-a_y)(c_y-b_y) = 0.$$

Now, substitute $c_x$ and $c_y$ into the second equation.  Solve for the number $t$.  Then, point $C$ is given by
$C = (a_x+t(p_x-a_x),a_y+t(p_y-a_y))$.

$$t = \frac{(a_x-b_x)^2+(a_y-b_y)^2}{(b_x-a_x)(p_x-a_x)+(b_y-a_y)(p_y-a_y)}.$$
Notice that this answer is in agreement with Hosam's answer.

Comment: To be honest I would not have found this approach, so I'm glad I asked for help. I'm struggling a bit to solve for t. After substitution of cx and cy in the second equation and simplifying on each side I now have t(bx - ax )(px - ax) - ax^2 - bx^2 = t(by - ay)(py - ay) - ay^2 + by^2. I don't see how I can isolate t even if I keep simplifying further.

Comment: Never mind, I kept simplifying and eventually got this: t = ax^2 + bx^2 - ay^2 + by^2 / (bxpx - axpx - bxax - ax^2 - bypy + aypy + byay + ay^2). Thanks Doug, will let you know and confirm if this works as intended.

Comment: I added a picture of the first implementation in my post. Point C does not appear where intended, but appears to be on the correct line. I may have made an error when solving for t, not sure. I'll take another crack at it.

Comment: @greenkarmic, perhaps there was a sign error?  When you solved for $t$, was it positive or negative?

Comment: I had tried to invert the sign of t but C but the point was just on the other side and there was still no 90deg angle in the triangle. I tried to solve for t again, and ended up with a completely different equation, and the result was similar, a point C on the line but no 90deg angle in the triangle. I must be doing something wrong.

t = (-axbx + bx2 - ax2 + axbx - ayby + by2 - ay2 + byay) / (pxbx - axbx - pxax - ax2 + pyby - ayby - pyay - ay2)

Comment: please check value of $t$.  I added to my answer.

Comment: I don't know where I went wrong but indeed using your value for t did the trick. Added image to my post and accepted answer. Thank you very much Doug.

Answer (score 1):

Find the angle between $AP$ and $AB$ using the formula

$ \theta = \cos^{-1} \left( \dfrac{ AP \cdot AB }{\| AP \| \| AB \| } \right)$

Then the distance $x$ from $A$ to $C$ is related to $\| AB\| $ and $\theta$ by

$ \cos( \theta) = \dfrac{ \| AB \| }{x } $

Hence,

$ x = \dfrac{ \| AB \|^2 \| AP \| }{ AP \cdot AB } $

Now point $C$ is along $AP$ but scaled up by a factor of $\dfrac{x}{\| AP \|} $

Therefore,

$\boxed{ C = A + \dfrac{ \| AB \|^2 }{AP \cdot AB} (AP) } $

So, for example, if $A = (-1, 0), B = (\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} ), P = (-\dfrac{1}{2}, 0 ) $, then

$ AP \cdot AB = (\dfrac{1}{2}, 0) \cdot (\dfrac{3}{2}, \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) = \dfrac{3}{4} $

and

$\| AB \|^2 = \dfrac{9}{4} + \dfrac{3}{4} = 3 $

Hence,

$C =  A + \dfrac{ \| AB \|^2 }{AP \cdot AB} (AP) = (-1, 0) + 3\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right) (\dfrac{1}{2}, 0) = (1, 0)$